# global variable in bash function not global if called with & to background the command

Tags: bash

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
#!/bin/bash

func2() {
    myarray=("e" "f")
}

func1() {
    myarray=("c" "d")
    for i in [1..10]
    do
        func2 &
    done
}

myarray=("a" "b")
func1
echo "${myarray[@]}"
```

The echo at the end should be

```
e f
```

but it ends up being

```
c d
```

because of the & when I call func2.  If I take out the & it runs as expected.  This is a proof of concept for a more complicated script I am using to make ssh calls to several servers at once.  I need the multi-threading capability of &, but since it seems to run in a subshell, all of its variables are local?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your questions is how to affect parent shell variables from a subshell, although you don't quite ask it.

There is no way to do that directly, but you can manage it by communicating with the background processes. The easiest way is to arrange them to write data to files after completion and then interpreting that. If you trust your subprocesses, simply make them write bash code and eval that in your parent process.

You might be able to detect when they finish using a trap on SIGCHLD.

Another way might be using [GNU "parallel"](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) tool and reaping the output files when it completes.

Yet another way could be using tools like ["parallel-ssh"](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/).

A more specific answer could be made if you provide more details.

Comment: I basically want to trap the output of stuff run in func2, sort it, then print it.  The problem now is that when I run the func1 & , all of the results from the 10 processes come back randomly i.e. not the order in which they were called.  Avoiding writing to a local file would be preferable, although not out of the question.

Comment: OK, then first of all you will need to store the output of each command until they all complete. If it's big, then storing it in files might be better than in memory. If it's small, you can try to simulate "select" or "poll" with bash "read" with timeouts reading from pipes connected to each process output, but it won't be effective.

Comment: However, "GNU parallel" does that for you, judging from its man page: "GNU parallel makes sure output from the commands is the same output as you would get had you run the commands sequentially."